# Error with modules calling modules

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def brent(n):
```

in a module prime. brent requires modules fractions, random

In my main module I do:

```
import prime # brent is found in here
import fractions # required for brent
import random # required for brent
```

When I call brent(n) it errors saying it can't find random. The fix is to place

```
import random
import fractions
```

INSIDE the original brent function.

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: are there multiple files in your scenario...

Comment: @avasal yes - brent is found in a separate module, primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (generally) import modules at the top of your own module, not inside functions.

A module import binds the imported names to the local scope, which means that if you import things inside a function, the names will only be available to that function and nothing else in your module.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. I have the modules imported at the top of my main module. The problem is those modules aren't detected by brent at the local scope

Comment: @nebffa: you don't share much code, but you talk about 'inside main *function*' and 'main module' as if they are the same. You need to import dependant modules *in each module you program*. So if `brent` is defined in a new module (a separate `.py` file) you need to import your modules you need there.

Comment: gotcha. I didn't want to show the code because it would take up the entire screen. Regardless, you've answered my question very well, even with the obfuscation I have accidentally put in by saying *main function/module* lol. I will import modules in the module where brent is stored - thankyou.